# CSS Menu link stays highlighted

Tags: css, menu

So I'm trying my hands at a css menu and I have a simple bug that I cannot fix and haven't found any help searching for it. The issue is that when I hover over a drop down menu the parent link stays highlighted and the text reverts back to the original color. Hopefully that explains it. Here's the css code, I'm sure it's a matter of adding something or fixing a line of code. You can check out the issue [here](http://www.pacycling.org), everything works fine until you visit a submenu (like in BAR or Info).

```
#nav, #nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    text-size:16px;
    float: left;
    width: 750px;
    height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    background: white;
    padding: 0;
    border: solid #000;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url('/images/bg.gif');
}

#nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #0000FF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    width: 75px;
}

#nav li ul { /*sub menu */
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    height: auto;
    width: 75px;
    border: solid #000;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    background-image: url('/images/submenu_bg.png');
}

#nav li li {
    width: 75px;
}

#nav li ul a {
    width: 75px;
}

#nav li ul ul {
    margin: -1.75em 0 0 14em;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul, #nav li li.sfhover ul, #nav li li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}

#nav li:hover, #nav li.sfhover {
    height: 20px;
    background: #0000FF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the text color on `#nav a:hover`, but the background color on `#nav li:hover`.  Because your submenus are contained within the `li`, it still counts as being hovered over even while the cursor is in the submenu.  The submenus *aren't* contained within the link, so they don't stay highlighted and revert to their normal color.  If you want the menu item to stop highlighting, move the `background` property to `#nav a:hover` instead.

Before:

```
#nav a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}

#nav li:hover, #nav li.sfhover {
    height: 20px;
    background: #0000FF;
}
```

After:

```
#nav a:hover, #nav li.sfhover a {
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #0000FF;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want the menu to *stay* highlighted while hovering on the submenu (which looks better, IMO), move `color` to the `li:hover`.  I know it's a little verbose, but it works.  :-)

Before:

```
#nav a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}

#nav li:hover, #nav li.sfhover {
    height: 20px;
    background: #0000FF;
}
```

After:

```
#nav a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
    height: 20px;
}

#nav li:hover a, #nav li.sfhover a {
    color:white;
}

#nav li:hover li a, #nav li.sfhover li a {
    color:blue;
}

#nav li:hover li a:hover, #nav li.sfhover li a:hover {
    color:white;
}

#nav li:hover, #nav li.sfhover {
    color: #FFF;
    height: 20px;
    background: #0000FF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the color of the link on the hover of the `li`, like so:

```
#nav li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

#nav li:hover li a
{
    color: #0000FF;
}
```

Comment: Need to fix the links under the sub-lists on hover: #nav li:hover li a:hover { color : #fff; }